# Go how to response csv file?

Tags: csv, go, multipartform-data

I am creating a server in Go and I want to respond with a CSV file.

I wrote the following, this does not cause the browser to download the CSV file. How can I prompt the browser to download the CSV file?

```
import "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"

type Test struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    Delete string
}

router.Get("/test", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)


    tests := []*Test{
        {
            ID:   1,
            Name: "a",
            Delete: "delete",
        },
        {
            ID:   2,
            Name: "b",
            Delete: "delete",
        },
    }

    w := multipart.NewWriter(writer)
    ww, err := w.CreateFormFile("file.csv", "file.csv")
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("CreateFormfile", zap.Error(err))
    }
    gocsv.Marshal(tests, ww)

})
```

Comment: Please _precisely_ define "not working". Actually that yould constitute the bigger part of your question. Unfortunately, the only answer one could give to the "it's not working" question is "there's some problem" which is not very useful. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I add the statement what problem is.

Comment: Hi penlight, what is the full import path of your `gocsv` dependency? Thanks.

Comment: I add gocsv import path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to tell the browser the to present the response as a file to download, you can use the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header:

```
rw.Header().Add("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="test.csv"`)
```

As far as outputting the CSV document itself,
I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by responding with a multipart encoding, but you should just marshal the CSV file directly into the original HTTP response writer:

```
router.Get("/test", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

        tests := []*Test{
            {
                ID:   1,
                Name: "a",
                Delete: "delete",
            },
            {
                ID:   2,
                Name: "b",
                Delete: "delete",
            },
        }

        gocsv.Marshal(tests, rw)

})
```

Comment: Just to complement the answer, adding `rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/csv")` might be a good idea. And if the response should trigger a download in the browser, instead of just being rendered, then also `rw.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=tests.csv")`.

Comment: Thank you. I want to download csv file.  I do not know necessary header. Your complement is helpful.

Comment: @mkopriva, based on the updated question, I'd say your comment is actually a proper answer, +1.